# How to launch autonomous robot (roslaunch machine/SSH)

Tags: roslaunch, ssh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have an autonomous robot that has to fulfill a mission without any connection to a base station. To launch the mission, we have two possible ways:

1. SSH to the robot, start a screen session, launch the mission.launch, detach the screen and close the SSH session. From this moment on the connection to the base station is not necessary any more. When the mission has ended (or was aborted) and the connection is established again we can SSH to the robot again, attach to the screen session and look at possible console output etc..
2. Launch a launch file from the base station that has `<node machine="robot" ... />` entries.

My question is what happens on connection loss when using option 2? How does roslaunch launch processes on the remote machines? Are these processes killed when the SSH connection times out?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27733/how-to-launch-autonomous-robot-(roslaunch-machine/ssh)/) by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1924 on 2012-02-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roslaunch actually uses an ssh connection to launch nodes remotely and keeps the ssh connection open until it needs to bring down the remote nodes again. I don't think option 2 would work in your scenario.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3